# Recent changes to FB.init and FB.login in the facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api

I have a script I use to import pictures from a facebook album. It was working yesterday but today it doesn’t work anymore. The popup with the login permission doesn’t open anymore. And the script don’t make the Facebook login remaining in FB.init.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

```
var loggedIn = false;



/*Logs the user into Facebook*/

function loginFacebook() {

    //initializes the facebook API

    FB.init({appId : "xxxxxxx", status : true,cookie : true,xbfml : true});



    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "In attesa del permesso Facebook";

    //opens the Facebook login window for user

    FB.login(function(response) {

        if (response.session) { 

            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Logged In. Ora puoi caricare gli album.";

            loggedIn = true;

            //disables the login button after the user has loggedIn

            document.getElementById("loginBtn").disabled = "Disabilitato";

            document.getElementById("loginBtn").style.display = "None";

            document.getElementById("albumBtn").style.display = "inline";

            document.getElementById("fb_logo").style.display = "None";

            document.getElementById("label_fb").style.display = "None";





        } else {

            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Non hai effettuato il Facebook Login";

            loggedIn = false;

        }

    },{perms:'user_photos'});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) it's recommended to use asynchronous loading, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

2) you **must** upgrade to OAuth 2.0 as mentioned in this blog [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/614/).
3) you have a typo `xbfml` it should be `xfbml`
4) you should use `scope` instead of `perms`
5) here's a rewrite of your code (putting the SDK *after* the `<body>` tag):

```
<head>
<!-- head content here -->

<!-- Include the normal stylesheet-->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        var loggedIn = false;
        var isLoaded = false;
        function loginFacebook() {
            if(!isLoaded) {
                alert("SDK is not yet loaded or something went wrong!");
                return false;
            }
            //initializes the facebook API
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "In attesa del permesso Facebook";
            //opens the Facebook login window for user
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {    
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Logged In. Ora puoi caricare gli album.";
                    loggedIn = true;
                    //disables the login button after the user has loggedIn
                    document.getElementById("loginBtn").disabled = "Disabilitato";
                    document.getElementById("loginBtn").style.display = "None";
                    document.getElementById("albumBtn").style.display = "inline";
                    document.getElementById("fb_logo").style.display = "None";
                    document.getElementById("label_fb").style.display = "None";


                } else {
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Non hai effettuato il Facebook Login";
                    loggedIn = false;
                }
            },{scope:'user_photos'});
        }
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
        // Additional initialization code here
        isLoaded = true;
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));
    </script>
<!-- rest of markup here -->
```

Comment: You are welcome. please try to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. As for other questions, try your best to solve your issue and then ask a new question with your code and issue explained.

Comment: ok, thanks now is loading the albums name but not the pics loaded by the next file. because the script is quite long I send you the link, maybe you could check if there is some other code not allowed be new API. Thanks!! :) [link]http://goo.gl/HY59u

Answer (score 0):

FB documentation says you need to use response.authResponse instead of response.session. More info [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Comment: I tetsed as well with response.authResponse but is not working as well, here the script:   FB.login(function(response) {

   if (response.authResponse) { 

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Logged In. Ora puoi caricare gli album.";

    loggedIn = true;

Comment: first of all make sure you've cleared cache and the script is updated (in case it's cached) then you can use browser debugger to determine where the calling thread stops at in the script and what's the problem